# No instance for (Monad (FormInput (HandlerT App IO)))

Tags: haskell, yesod

My issue is:

> No instance for `(Monad (FormInput (HandlerT App IO)))`

is such code:

```
postTest :: Handler Value
postTest = requireAuthId 
           >>= \ pId -> runInputPost $ (,) <$> ireq intField "a" 
                                           <*> ireq intField "b" 
           >>= \ (a, b) -> return $ toJSON $ object []
```

How can I solve this issue? How will the instance look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a syntax issue to me, I think you just need to wrap `runInputPost..."b"` inside parentheses. But is there a reason you're not using `do`-notation for this? I'd find it more natural, and less likely to lead to these syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by the text of error. I have written similar handlers. All of them are compilable and workable. First time I see such error. I use `do`'s. But this is just an interest.